# Javascript html page not loading, innerHTML not targetting

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code on the html file. I am using a flatpickr date picker and taking the users selected date On calendar close and wanting to update the current document to add some html but it is not working there are no error messages anywhere.

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="calendar">
        <h3 class="date-header">Set availability:</h3>

        <form>
            <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" placeholder=" Select date-time">
        </form>

        <div class="current_availability" style="margin-top: 100px; height: 50px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;
        border-width: 2px">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!--flatpickr date picker-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <script>
        config = {
        enableTime: true,
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
            altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y h:i K",
            minDate: "2024-01",
            onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                document.getElementById('current_availability').innerHTML=  `<h3> Available sessions:</h3>
                <p>hi</p>`;
    }
        }

        fp = flatpickr("input[type=datetime-local]", config);
        console.log(fp.selectedDates)
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

I've tried messing with the div styling and using querySelector instead but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `class` to `id` at `current_availability` and add the css:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="calendar">
    <h3 class="date-header">Set availability:</h3>

    <form>
      <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" placeholder=" Select date-time">
    </form>

    <div id="current_availability" style="margin-top: 100px; height: 50px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;
        border-width: 2px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--flatpickr date picker-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script>
  config = {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y h:i K",
    minDate: "2024-01",
    onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      document.getElementById('current_availability').innerHTML = `<h3> Available sessions:</h3>
                <p>hi</p>`;
    }
  }

  fp = flatpickr("input[type=datetime-local]", config);
  console.log(fp.selectedDates)
</script>
```